# Jquery: default selection on hidden select options

Tags: jquery

I have a select option list, it's display:none, so hidden. I do need to have a default option selected, based on a url, applied to this hidden option list.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/nl/boom/") > -1) {
   $('select option:contains("Boom1")').prop('selected',true);
   }
```

The code above works, but only when the select option list is visible (display:block or  visibility: visible). Its not an option to have the select list visible.

However, the option list becomes visible, depending on selected previous options.
Also it 's always select option number 4 on the page.

Hope you can help

Comment: Visibility of an element should have no effect on the logic you have provided.  Please edit your question to include an example of the issue.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, i just need to know how i can make a selection option selected by default, when it not displayed by css rules.

Comment: the logic that you have is a conditional based on the index of a value in the url.  That is not affected by anything visible or not visible.  Then your following selector is looking for option elements that contain the string `Boom1`, of which belong to a select element.  That also is not affected by anything visible or not visible on the page.  So your statement that says it works so long as something is visible, is very likely an incomplete statement of the problem.

Comment: I just want to know how i can make a default value selection on a select list, at the moment the select list is becoming visible for the viewer.